# Full text search query is slow on first query

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

I have an `airports` table which contains a list of nearly 4k airports. The table has a `searchable` column which is a `ts_vector` column and an index `airports_searchable_index`:

```sql
searchable tsvector NULL

CREATE INDEX airports_searchable_index ON airports USING gin (searchable)
```

Given I have an indexed document in the `searchable` column and I attempt to run a query against that column, I get very quick responses on my dev machine (around 3ms for the query) but around 650ms on production (using the exact same data!). The weird part is that my production machine is **much** stronger than my local dev machine. A query for example:

```sql
select * from "airports" where searchable @@ to_tsquery('public.hebrew', 'ltn:*') order by "popularity" desc limit 100
```

I've opened PGAdmin and tried doing some tests. What I saw that for the first time I run the query above in a new "Query Tool Panel", it takes anywhere between 650-800ms to execute. However, on the second run, it takes 30-60ms to run **even if I change the query term**. I had concluded from that, that Postgres is possible opening the document in memory for each connection and run the query against that. Since I'm using PHP to talk with my backend, every request is going to open it's own connection to the DB, hence causing Postgres to constantly re-opening the document.

Could it be a misconfiguration on my production server?

Here is an `explain` query (for **production** server):

```
Limit  (cost=24.03..24.04 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.048..0.048 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: id, popularity
  Buffers: shared hit=4
  ->  Sort  (cost=24.03..24.04 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.047..0.047 rows=1 loops=1)
        Output: id, popularity
        Sort Key: airports.popularity DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        Buffers: shared hit=4
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on lametayel.airports  (cost=20.01..24.02 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.040..0.040 rows=1 loops=1)
              Output: id, popularity
              Recheck Cond: (airports.searchable @@ '''ltn'':*'::tsquery)
              Heap Blocks: exact=1
              Buffers: shared hit=4
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on airports_searchable_index  (cost=0.00..20.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.036..0.036 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (airports.searchable @@ '''ltn'':*'::tsquery)
                    Buffers: shared hit=3
Planning time: 0.304 ms
Execution time: 0.078 ms
```

Here is an `explain` query (for **development** server):

```sql
Limit  (cost=28.03..28.04 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.065..0.067 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: id, popularity
  Buffers: shared hit=5
  ->  Sort  (cost=28.03..28.04 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.064..0.065 rows=1 loops=1)
        Output: id, popularity
        Sort Key: airports.popularity DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        Buffers: shared hit=5
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on lametayel.airports  (cost=24.01..28.02 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.046..0.047 rows=1 loops=1)
              Output: id, popularity
              Recheck Cond: (airports.searchable @@ '''ltn'':*'::tsquery)
              Heap Blocks: exact=1
              Buffers: shared hit=5
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on airports_searchable_index  (cost=0.00..24.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.038..0.038 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (airports.searchable @@ '''ltn'':*'::tsquery)
                    Buffers: shared hit=4
Planning time: 0.534 ms
Execution time: 0.122 ms
```

Comment: The execution plan shows that the query got done in less than 0.4 milliseconds and touched 4 blocks. You'll have to give us an execution plan for a case where it takes half a second (so, something from the production database).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe This is the execution plan that takes 700ms (production server). The explain shows a super quick lookup but it takes more than that in reality

Comment: It doesn't in the database. Perhaps there is something in your application or the network that causes a slowdown, but `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` doesn't lie to you. If anything, the execution time shown is bigger than in reality, because the measurements are a non-neglectable overhead.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've been using PGAdmin and DBeaver to query the database directly instead of PHP. Do you think the issue is the time it takes to connect to the production database and parsing the query? When I use PDO to measure the time it took the query to run I get the 700ms result. Where should I begin debugging this?

Comment: I'd use profiling on the application to see where the time is spent. Establishing a database connection for each query would be a killer, but even with that 700 ms seems out of proportion. You could set `log_min_duration_statement` to 0 and `log_connections` to `on` and see when you find in the database log.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe there is one thing I forgot to mention. When I run a simple `like` query against the database in both production and development, the execution time is roughly the same. The difference only happens while I use the full-text search. Does it give you an idea what's going on or your previous suggestion still stands?

Comment: Perhaps a different execution plan is used. You can use `auto_explain` to capture the execution plan that the application uses.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've added the execution plan for the development server. As you can see it is almost identical. In fact, the development server execution time should be marginally slower than production, but in reality, the response is coming back **much** faster. I'm kind of lost here. Not sure what to check next

Comment: Well, at least you know that the database is not the problem.